# C++11. Move semantics for lvalue reference in return statement

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

In C++11/14 we have: Return value optimization, move semantics, some classes like [unique_ptr](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) which don't have copy ctor

Q1: What is a correct behavior of the code snippet below when DECLARE_COPY_CTOR is equal to 1 or to zero ?

Q2: Console application built with MSVC 2013 for code snippet below in DEBUG build for Win32 gives in console: A(), **A(A&&)**, ~A(), ~A(). So looks like lvalue referencce "a" was used to bind to "A&&". Is it legal? I thought that only temporary objects can be a candidate for move.

Q3: In RELEASE build compiler choose to use Rvo (so output was: A(), ~A())

Is compiler free to choose is "a" in function scope is a canditate for move?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#define DECLARE_COPY_CTOR 0

class A
{
public:
    A() {puts("A()");}
    ~A() { puts("~A()"); }

#if DECLARE_COPY_CTOR
    A(A&) { puts("A(A&)"); }
#endif

    A(A&&) { puts("A(A&&)"); }
    A& operator = (A&) { puts("A& operator = (A&)"); return *this; }
};

A F()
{
    A a;       // here a is lvalue
    return a;  // here a is still lvalue
}

int main()
{
    auto i = F();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Q1. What is a correct behavior of the code snippet below when DECLARE_COPY_CTOR is equal to 1 or to zero ?

`DECLARE_COPY_CTOR` has no effect on the behaviour. Copy constructor is not invoked in the program.

> Q2. So looks like lvalue referencce "a"

`a` is an lvalue, but it isn't an lvalue *reference*.

> Q2. Is it legal?

Yes, it is legal to return a non-copyable **local** lvalue. It will be moved.

> Q3. Is compiler free to choose is "a" in function scope is a canditate for move?

If the type of returned local variable is movable, then it *must* be moved rather than copied. NRVO applies to this case, so the compiler is free to elide the move - just like it was free to elide the copy prior to c++11.